# Combine two Shiny scripts together for R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

My R Shiny app contains two different JS scripts in the UI:

1. One to load the msal library

`shiny::tags$script(src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.30.0/js/msal-browser.min.js")`

2. And another custom script that uses that library to runs some db oauth token negotiation:

```
  shiny::tags$script(HTML("
        async function wrapperFunc() {
                const msalConfig = {
                    auth: {
                        clientId: 'XXXX',
                        authority: 'XXXXX'
                    }
                };
                const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
                const silentRequest = {
                    scopes: ['api://XXXXX']
                };
                const callLogin = async function(silentRequest, msalInstance) {
                    try {
                        const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(silentRequest);
                        return loginResponse;
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                }
                response = callLogin(silentRequest, msalInstance);
              return response;
      }
      wrapperFunc().then(result => {
            Shiny.setInputValue('oauthToken', result['accessToken']);
                      console.log(result['accessToken']);
      });"))
```

Is there a way to combine the two `tags$script` calls into one?  I am asking because I would like to create a catch-all custom function that encapsulates the two, because it is a standard bit of code used in all reporting across my organization. Packaging this bit of code would remove the need to copy and paste the JS scripts across different reports.

I hope I am making sense!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was super simple - wrap them both up in a tags$head script!